# "No messenger will aid you until you have discovered their resting place"

Tags: the-talos-principle

Sometimes at the beginning of a puzzle, there is a white-board I can click on.  When I click on it, my character leaves a message asking for help.  The reply is always the same:

> No messenger will aid you until you have discovered their resting place.  Return here then to seek their counsel.

How do I "discover a messenger's resting place?"  And what exactly do these boards do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though @janb already answered it. I would like to add more details.

1. White-boards are used for small hints, like "Try to make it as high as possible". Only 3 hints are possible in the game, as far as I know. *(You can also redeem three extra hints by playing the (free) promotional game "Sigils of Elohim" and redeeming the codes it gives you for those hints. (с) Jonathan Thiele)*
2. They are present only at puzzles with red sigils, as far as I noted. But all those puzzles are totally managable with out hints.
3. There are 3 messenger's resting places, one per hall. They are behind boarded up doors.
4. You can unlock the doors only when you reach hall-C. To reach it you need to collect all green sigils at halls A and B.

Comment: Also, you will need to break down the boarded up doors with the red ax in hall-C in order to be able to access the resting places.

Comment: You can also redeem three extra hints by playing the (free) promotional game "Sigils of Elohim" and redeeming the codes it gives you for those hints, but that might be a bit too much work.

Answer (score 3):

The white-boards are the implementation of a hint system. If you click them, you can see hints for the puzzle. However, this hint system only unlocks in World C where you can actually find the Messengers on three islands and awaken them.