# Are some areas impassable until late game?

Tags: the-talos-principle

I've read that there are certain areas that seem to be impassable early, only to become possible after returning much later. Do I just have to go back later, or is there always a way to complete each puzzle on the first visit?

Answer (score 2):

Every puzzle can be completed as soon as you can enter it.

Of course, some puzzles require a particular item to be unlocked, but assuming you were diligently collecting Sigils, as Elohim told you to, you should always have enough of them to unlock the item before even entering a puzzle area that requires it. ***If*** you try to solve one such puzzle, the game will notify you about retrieving the item first, so you'll know not to attempt an impossible puzzle.

There is however a door in hub world A, sealed with wooden planks, which you'll need an axe in order to get through. The axe can be found in hub world C, near the end of the game. If you want to complete the game 100%, a little bit of backtracking is therefore necessary.

Everything else can be completed the moment you encounter it. Some puzzles just require thinking outside the box, especially the stars which might require...

> combining assets from multiple puzzles within an area

for instance.

Comment: What about the puzzles that say "No messenger will aid you until you have discovered their resting place. Return here then to seek their counsel."? I saw one of those, and as far as I can see it is uncompleteable.

Comment: @Scootaloo. The "messenger" is simply the hint system in the game. You need to have progressed a bit in order to find them. There are 3 messengers, each can only be used once, so you only get hints for solving 3 puzzles. The point of these messengers is that you should only use them to help you solve the 3 puzzles you have the most difficulty with.

Comment: @Scootaloo http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202828/no-messenger-will-aid-you-until-you-have-discovered-their-resting-place

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There are 5 items that need to be unlocked using Tetromino pieces (aka Sigils) before you can use them to solve puzzles.

They are:

- Connector - Located in World A. Allows you to connect laser emitters to laser receivers.
- Hexahedron - Located in World A.  It's a box.  You stand on it.
- Fan - Located in World B.  Used to blow things (including you) around.
- Recorder - Located in World C.  Used to record yourself doing things.  Once you begin playback, you can interact with what the other you is doing.
- The Platform - Located in World C.  Used while recording for the real you to place items (or themselves) on top of.

There is a sign by every puzzle showing which items you need to complete it.  Items you don't yet have should be marked with red Xs.

Now, as for the Tetrominoes:

- Green (easy) pieces open up puzzles hubs  (specifically Worlds A, B, and C).
- Yellow (medium) pieces unlock items.
- Red (hard) pieces are used in The Tower.
- Grey (extra hard) pieces are... a secret.

Comment: The Platform may also be an unlock... I don't remember if it is or not.  It's always used in conjunction with The Recorder.  I'll have to check when I get home or something.